# how to filter with multiple values from checkboxes in Django?

Tags: django, orm

I have this Patient model with fields: company, sex, is_alive...

In the patient search page, I have checkboxes for these fields. So if users want to search all *male* *alive* patient in a *company* ... they will tick on the checkbox.

Then in the backend, in views.py, I collect values of checkboxes and put into a list called "value_list". Next, I do the query search like this:

```
patient_list = Patient.objects.all()

if "abc" in value_list:
        company = Company.objects.get(name="abc")
        patient_list = patient_list.filter(Q(company=company))

if "alive" in value_list:
        patient_list = patient_list.filter(Q(is_alive=True))

if "male" in value_list:
        patient_list = patient_list.filter(Q(sex=MALE))
```

My question is if this way of filtering is efficient and good practice.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of performance, everything looks fine.  You will end up executing 1 query with this code because Django is smart enough to know to combine these into 1 large query that uses several subqueries.

That being said, you can massively simplify this with the `__in` clause, which is simply a shorthand for multiple `or` conditions:

```
Patient.objects.filter(company__in=Company.objects.filter(name__in=values_list)))
```

Comment: Thank you Caleb! I appreciate your help!

Comment: How about if you need to AND the conditions?